The relation $Z^{-1}\phi(x)Z=-\phi(x)$ for a classical field $\phi$, and unitary operator $Z$ in Srednicki's book
Most QFT textbooks treat spontaneous symmetry breaking (SSB) classically. They start with a classical field, $\phi(x)$, which is a $c$-number function, described by a Lagrangian density invariant under a group of transformations. Then, the potential minima are obtained (denoted by $\phi_0$, say). If the classical minima are degenerate, we have SSB. Then at the end, the classical minima, $\phi_0$, are interpreted as the vacuum expectation value, $\langle 0|\hat{\phi}|0\rangle$, of a quantum field $\hat{\phi}$.
I am somewhat confused by Chapter 30, Eq. 30.2 of Mark Srednicki's QFT book. Let me quote this portion from the book as it is.

Consider $\phi^4$ theory, where $\phi$ is a real scalar field with Lagrangian
\begin{equation}
    \mathcal{L} = -\frac{1}{2} \partial_{\mu} \phi \partial^{\mu} \phi - \frac{1}{2} m^2 \phi^2 - \frac{1}{24} \lambda \phi^4. 
    \tag{30.1}
\end{equation}
As we discussed in section 23, this theory has a $Z_2$ symmetry: $\mathcal{L}$ is invariant under $\phi(x) \rightarrow -\phi(x)$, and we can define a unitary operator $Z$ that implements this:
\begin{equation}
    Z^{-1}\phi(x)Z   = -\phi(x).
    \tag{30.2}
\end{equation}
We also have $Z^2 = 1$, and so $Z^{-1} = Z$. Since unitarity implies $Z^{-1} = Z^{\dagger}$, this makes $Z$ Hermitian as well as unitary.

If the classical field theory is invariant under $\phi(x)\to -\phi(x)$, does this mean that we can define a unitary operator $Z$ such that $$Z^{-1}\phi(x)Z=-\phi(x)$$ even when $\phi$ is a classical field? We don't talk about unitary operators in classical field theory. Shouldn't such a relation hold for the quantum field $\hat{\phi}$?

If the classical functions are considered elements of $L^2(\mathbb{R}^4)$ then it is still easy to act on them with unitary operators.

FWIW: Yes, Srednicki assumes that $\phi$ in eq. (30.2) is a quantum field rather than a classical field.
